# Can't find any new guides and documentation on WPF localization

Tags: .net, wpf, localization, resources

So, I want to localize my app, but I can't find any new guides or documentation, usually the guides either for .NET framework written in like 2015, or guides, that are using RESX, isn't there another way to localize the app instead of using RESX and `{x:Static}` binding. I know there is RESW, but it looks like that RESW is only supported in UWP.

Comment: I don't think localization has changed the much since 2015.

Comment: @Joe so basically, I can't avoid using RESX? I just think that it is kinda like a workaround.

Comment: Is there anything particularly difficult or wrong with .RESX?   I am not familiar with .RESW so I do not understand the problem.

Comment: If it would help, I could tell you how I did it with .RESX files.   Our app supports multiple languages and formats numbers/dates according to the culture/locale of language in question without too much work.  We cannot change languages on the fly (you must restart the app) but aside from that it works quite well.  We just grab our strings from the same RESX file regardless of the current language and the properly translate string comes out.

Comment: I've used resource dictionaries instead of resx in the past. Merge English then merge a different language over it if necessary. Use dynamic resource to reference all your strings. You can then localise and brand with the same mechanism.  Resource dictionaries can even be merged from uncompiled .xaml files allowing customisation. You can supply to a third party who add their own custom resource dictionary.

Comment: @Joe, I'm fine with restarting the app, so, I just need a nice guide on how to implement it, like, for example WinForms, there was their own localization method using RESX, UWP had RESW and .strings file, as far as I remember, but the plain WPF and WinUI 3, I don't really know how to correctly implement localization, because LocBaml is deprecated as far as I know (at least it doesn't work on .NET 6 and higher according to MSDN), and RESX just feels old for me, and that's why I'm asking about new tools, if RESX still used by official SDK, then I also will use it.

Comment: OK I posted an answer showing what I do.  I double it is the best way but it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give you a definitive guide, but here is a simple way to localize strings and number/date formatting in WPF.  This is the approach I cobbled together from various answers here and other websearching.

Note that, as we discussed in this example, there is no ability for the user to be able to change the language on the fly;  Once the language is changed, the app must  be restarted.

Suppose your app is one module, named `MyCompany.MyApp`.  You put all of your strings into a RESX file named `MyStrings.resx`.  When you build it the output folder might look like this

```
\net8.0-windows
    MyCompany.MyApp.exe
    MyCompany.MyApp.dll
```

This works fine for English but you want to add... French and Japanese.  You want not only strings translated into whichever of those languages is current, but you also want number/date formatting to follow that language's default culture.

First, create two new RESX files.  `MyStrings.fr.resx` and `MyStrings.ja.resx`, right alongside the main `MyStrings.resx`.  The key is to use the two-letter lanugage code in the name.  You can delete the backing .CS file from these new files;  You only need it for the main one.

Each of these will hold the translations of every string in `MyStrings.resx` for that language.

Next, come up with some way to save to settings an identifier for the lanuguage configured.

At application startup, before you do anything else, get that saved language code from your settings and then obtain (from the system) the `CultureInfo` for that language.  Use it to set thread cultures.  You can use `ResourceManager.GetResourceSet` to obtain it the various cultures.  Once you have obtained the `CultureInfo` for the language that is going to be used, set the thread cultures in this way.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = languageCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture  = languageCulture;
```

What the above buys you is automatic selection of the appropriate string from the appropriate .RESX file based upon the language culture you chose at startup.  So if your C# code refers to a string resource in `MyStrings.resx` like this

```
var str = MyStrings.SomeStringResource
```

...or if your XAML refers to it like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static res:MyStrings.SomeStringResource}"/>
```

The string chosen will be automatically selected from the appropriate .RESX file.  If the current language you set up is Japanese, it will be chosen from `MyStrings.ja.resx`.  If it is French it will be chosen from `MyStrings.fr.resx`.  if it is English or if it is some culture that you do not have a .RESX file for, it will be chosen from `MyStrings.resx`

Finally, to deal with number/date formatting, you need to Set this language on the FrameworkElement class metadata. To illustrate, assume that `languageCulture` below is the `CultureInfo` of the currently configured language which you obtained at startup.

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(languageCulture.Name)));
```

Again, this must be one early before any UI shows.  But once you do this, every single call to `IValueConverter.Convert` or `IMultiValueConverter.Convert` will receive a CultureInfo that is appropriate for the configured language, regardless of the OS configuration.

When you build your project, you will see new subdirectories in the build output.  Each subdirectory holds the resource DLLs for a single language.  Like this

```
\net8.0-windows
    MyCompany.MyApp.exe
    MyCompany.MyApp.dll
    \fr
        MyCompany.MyApp.Resources.dll
    \ja
        MyCompany.MyApp.Resources.dll
```

You will want to ship these with your installed project.

Every time you need to add a new language, all you need is a new .RESX file, you'll get a new subdirectory.

I'm sure there are better ways, more sophisticated ways. But this suits our purpose.  Our strings are translated and our number/date formatting looks good